# Eclipse CDT .cproject file from Windows to Unix

Tags: eclipse, build, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I have a legacy, in-house tool that creates an Eclipse CDT project out of all the C files that I use to run Simulink simulations. I use the eclipse project as front end to GDB (in Windows using Cygwin) to debug by simulation C code. The tool uses an unchanging `.cproject` file to make the projects.

I am now running my simulations on Unix so I'm trying to port the tool to create an Eclipse project in Unix. I am stuck on how to turn my Windows `.cproject` file into a Unix `.cproject` file. For example in Unix Eclipse project build is giving me errors like below:

```
Managed Build system manifest file error: Option cdt.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.path.2110017774 
uses a null category that is invalid in its context. The option was ignored.
```

I am guessing that this is being caused by the `.cproject` file since it is the only file in the tool that has `cdt.managedbuild` in it.

```
<option id="cdt.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.path.2110017774" 
superClass="cdt.managedbuild.option.gnu.cross.path" value="MinGWPath" valueType="string"/>
```

I don't even understand what this file is doing or how it was generated in the first place. I did not create the tool and I am an Eclipse novice. Are there any resources that I could use to understand how to create, modify, and interpret a .cproject file?

Answer (score 2):

`.cproject` files aren't really designed to be generated by external tools. Their exact format is not documented, and is considered to be an implementation detail.

Extensibility and automation in the Eclipse ecosystem is intended to happen through Eclipse plugins. Eclipse plugins have access to a set of stable, documented APIs which can be used to manipulate an Eclipse workspace. For example, for creating a project you might use APIs like [`IWorkspaceRoot.getProject()`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IWorkspaceRoot.html#getProject-java.lang.String-), [`IProject.create()`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IProject.html#create-org.eclipse.core.resources.IProjectDescription-org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor-), and [`CoreModel.create(IProject)`](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/cdt/core/model/CoreModel.html#create-IProject-). The implementation of these APIs will take care of details such as creating the `.cproject` file.

If you really want to generate the `.cproject` file yourself, your best bet is to refer to the [CDT source code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/) for details about its exact format, and ask any clarifying questions on the [CDT mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/cdt-dev). It may also be helpful to look at the source code of other cross-platform tools that create `.cproject` files, such as [CMake](https://cmake.org/) which has an Eclipse project generator.