# Create Eclipse project using `make`?

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to create Eclipse project using `make`?

I have a bunch of Eclipse CDT c++ projects, but I can't keep the `.project` and `.cproject` files in the source reposotory - instead, one option is to create a `makefile` to be able to re-create Eclipse projects by running `make`. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

CMake can [generate Eclipse project files](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/editors/Eclipse-CDT4-Generator), you could use that. I haven't come across a way to do it using plain `make`.

That said, please keep in mind the caveats I mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43530232/141719) about Eclipse project file formats being undocumented and without guarantees of stability.