# Seemingly random numbers in Eclipse project files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Looking at Eclipse `.cproject` and `.project` files I see many seemingly random numbers:

```
<targetPlatform id="cdt.managedbuild.target.gnu.platform.mingw.exe.debug.928002373"
<tool id="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.assembler.mingw.exe.debug.1473978281"
<inputType id="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.assembler.input.1028037841" 
<tool id="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.archiver.mingw.base.917558104"
 etc...
```

What are the numbers for?

I am writing a script that generates the files, and I am unsure if I need to change those numbers for each project I generate the files for - or they can stay the same?

Projects may be open in same workspace, so I am affraid of some kind of collisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[They really are just random numbers](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.core/model/org/eclipse/cdt/core/settings/model/util/CDataUtil.java?id=ef2b34f148e7f6be1e91273754dd9a2f869cf49e#n101).

I traced the addition of the random part of the identifiers back to [a commit in 2003](https://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/commit/?id=cc6084024dd2af4d5b3c4287f5e9fbae20d84a2a), which references [Eclipse bug 44020](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=44020).

That bug concerns a workspace with two projects, where the include paths of the projects get confused. The explanation provided is:

> The problem appears to
>   have been caused by overlapping IDs in the build model. I have added code to
>   make the IDs more unique and with a clean workspace, I can no longer get this
>   behaviour to occur.

So, it would seem that certain settings are grouped by some identifier (e.g. of a build configuration), and this can happen across projects in a given workspace – or at least that was the case in 2003. (The code is much too convoluted for me to assess whether that's still the case.)

Anyways, to be on the safe side, I would make the IDs in the generated file unique across different projects in the workspace.

---

That said, on the more general topic of writing a script to generate `.cproject` files, I would suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43530232).

Comment: Thanks @HighCommander4. I was going to replace all the numbers with random ones, however, some numbers appear at several places, others are completely unique... pretty hard to get my head around this.